# Custom datepicker binding with parent component using Angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm trying to set up a shared `DatePicker` component to be used on different pages in the application.

I'm working with Angular 4 and trying to use `ngbDatepicker`. For some reason, the date selection after toggle does not bind with the parent component when I am using this shared directive element.

Date changed in picker from button should come in an app component. I tried with `input` and `output` also, but those did not work. I also looked at something called `ControlValueAccessor` which did not work well.

datepicker-poput.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {forwardRef} from '@angular/core';
import {ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-datepicker-popup',
  templateUrl: './datepicker-popup.html',
   providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => NgbdDatepickerPopup),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class NgbdDatepickerPopup implements ControlValueAccessor{
  model;
  propagateChange = (_: any) => {};

  constructor() { }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    console.log('writeValue', obj);
    this.model = obj;
    //this.propagateChange(this.model);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  changeMe() {
    this.propagateChange(this.model);
  }
}
```